# CodeIgntier 3 using native sessions instead of CI's drivers

Tags: codeigniter

Would this be the best way to use the native php sessions instead of using their drivers? Since their drivers are just wrappers around session functions; I figured this would be the easiest way.

The reason behind this is I am having issues with locking with mysql database driver and redis driver. I want to use native php sessions and swap in a redis driver at the php level.

This seems to work well. Any thoughts?

```
<?php
class MY_Session extends CI_Session 
{
    public function __construct(array $params = array())
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // No sessions under CLI
        if (is_cli())
        {
            log_message('debug', 'Session: Initialization under CLI aborted.');
            return;
        }
        elseif ((bool) ini_get('session.auto_start'))
        {
            log_message('error', 'Session: session.auto_start is enabled in php.ini. Aborting.');
            return;
        }

        // Configuration ...
        $this->_configure($params);
        $this->_config['_sid_regexp'] = $this->_sid_regexp;

        // Sanitize the cookie, because apparently PHP doesn't do that for userspace handlers
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('#\A'.$this->_sid_regexp.'\z#', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
        {
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
        }

        session_start();

        // Is session ID auto-regeneration configured? (ignoring ajax requests)
        if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) OR strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest')
            && ($regenerate_time = config_item('sess_time_to_update')) > 0
        )
        {
            if ( ! isset($_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate']))
            {
                $_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] = time();
            }
            elseif ($_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] < (time() - $regenerate_time))
            {
                $this->sess_regenerate((bool) config_item('sess_regenerate_destroy'));
            }
        }
        // Another work-around ... PHP doesn't seem to send the session cookie
        // unless it is being currently created or regenerated
        elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]) && $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']] === session_id())
        {
            setcookie(
                $this->_config['cookie_name'],
                session_id(),
                (empty($this->_config['cookie_lifetime']) ? 0 : time() + $this->_config['cookie_lifetime']),
                $this->_config['cookie_path'],
                $this->_config['cookie_domain'],
                $this->_config['cookie_secure'],
                TRUE
            );
        }
        $this->_ci_init_vars();     
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't get it - it looks similar to CIs Session library - is this related to your question which has a bounty on ? And what do you mean with _I am having issues with locking_ ? What causes your locking problem? i think you have to add a bit more information. Despite the fact - i don't even understand what your intention is ;)

Comment: The session driver for redis tries to get a lock every second for 30 seconds; which is pretty slow. The native session's in phpredis library makes this more configurable. If you look at the Session library in Codeigniter I copied the constutor and removed the parts that setup a custom session handler for drivers.

Comment: I want to be able to use set_userdata and other methods of session class BUT NOT use drivers (native session implantation)

Comment: i'm not sure if this is your problem - when we had massive performance issues (because we use angular as a frontend framework) - we needed to use `session_write_close()`. - There is a section in CIs documentation. (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class) - this helped a lot - maybe thats your problem ? _Using sessions without locks can cause all sorts of problems, especially with heavy usage of AJAX, and we will not support such cases. Use session_write_close() after you’ve done processing session data if you’re having performance issues._

Comment: I am aware of this, the problem is that the session redis driver for codeigniter has poor performance with locking. If it cannot get a lock, it waits 1 second and tries again for 30 times. This can be really slow. If I use php redis session driver it is a lot faster. This requires modification to session library (which I have done). I just want verification I didn’t miss anything

Comment: It's hard to make any guess without actually seeing your code (not the session management code, but whatever else uses it). The fact that you're experiencing session locks is very likely not related to the session management at all, but to how you use that session management. I run quite a few codeigniter-based sites with DB-based sessions, one of which gets around 4 hits per second in the database table. Never had a locking issue. Maybe your db server is underpowered? maybe you're running other code while the table is locked, thus keeping the table locked longer than you need?

Comment: Again this isn't a question about locking but if the way I override the Session library makes sense.

Comment: I understand. However it's hard not to address the original/base issue (if you weren't experiencing locks you probably wouldn't be going through all this hassle), as conventional wisdom suggests that fixing the cause of such locking would be better than working around it in the long run.